# how many different customer hierarchies exist in a customer data set

Tags: data-cleaning

looking for some ideas that lead to a starting point on how to define all existing hierarchies in a data set.

e.g. A customer database has many different customer hierarchies. how could one find the different ones and attribute how many customers belong to each?